# Starting up 2 instances of the same service?

Tags: android

I've developed an Android service that I auto-start with the following code :

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    <!-- Declare Boot Completed Broadcast Receiver, For Service Auto-Start on Boot -->
    <receiver android:name=".utils.os.ServiceAutoStart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

ServiceAutoStart.java :

```
public class ServiceAutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Start Patch Service On Boot
        context.startService(new Intent(context, PatchService.class));
    }
}
```

In addition, I have a "Viewer" that starts and binds to the service using startService() and bindService().  For the most part everything works as expected.  Recently I noticed that if I immediately open my "Viewer" application as soon an my Android device boot up, I seem to create 2 instance of the service (see image below).  I didn't think it was possible to create 2 instances of the same service.  What is going on here?  Am I misinterpreting what I'm seeing in DDMS?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I seem to create 2 instance of the service (see image below)

If you are referring to your semi-redacted list of debuggable processes on the left, they are two separate *apps*. One is `com.XXXX.service` and one is `com.XXXX.serviceremote`.

> I didn't think it was possible to create 2 instances of the same service

It's not. They are separate instances of separate services in separate apps.

Comment: Will the process that handles the auto-start code show up separate from the service in DDMS? Is that what I am seeing?

Comment: @JesseJ: No. You have written and installed three separate apps. You can see their package names in DDMS (redacted in your screenshot). These apps presumably did not get there by elven magic or out of work space aliens. They are there because you wrote them, you installed them, and you are running code that is starting up all three of them. Why you did this, and what you are expecting out of these three apps, I cannot say.

Comment: @JesseJ: Your question and comment suggest that you think that there should be only one app. There are three apps. If you do not know what those apps are or why they are there, uninstall them from your device, then see if you start getting errors/warnings in LogCat that are tied to these mysterious extra apps.

Comment: Thanks for you help and suggestions.  I'm clearly missing something.  I'll have to look into this some more.

Comment: @JesseJ: One semi-common source of this problem is refactoring. Did you perhaps start with App A in package A, then move it into package B or something? If you did, and you did not install the old app, the old app will still be on your device (under package A). If they *both* have boot-time receivers, they'd both get control and both do things. That might explain at least one of the rogue apps.